# Portable application for calculating Whirlpool hash of a file

Tags: windows, portable

Do you know any **portable** software which is able to calculate Whirlpool hash of a file?
I know [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/), but this app requires OS installation, not portable.

Comment: It helps if you specify your OS. [Edit your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/13649/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Hash Generator](http://securityxploded.com/hashgenerator.php)

- Runs on Windows
- Calculates several types of hashes with a single click, including Whirlpool
- [**Portable** version here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/HashGenerator.shtml). Just extract the zip archive and run

[image]

Comment: Actually, I'm absolutely disappointed and I won't be able to use this app in a real life. I'm going to hash relatively huge files (up to 1GB and even bigger), but this HashGenerator is forcing me to waste a **lot** of time waiting for **all types of hashes** to be generated!!! I can't even find the right words to express my annoyance. Where's the option to generate only selected types of hashes (as HashTab does)???  
And by the way, this app limits the text input up to 250 chars... but that's another story

Comment: @lyricallywicked You are right. Having to wait for all the hash types is both annoying and impractical. Better luck in your follow up question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for a truly portable solution, i.e. will run on any machine regardless of OS, I would suggest getting a USB key and installing [portable python](http://portablepython.com/) and adding the pure python implementation of [Whirlpool](http://www.bjrn.se/code/whirlpoolpy.txt).

Note that the original code needed to be extended to allow use from the command line to hash files - I have uploaded the modified file to [github](https://github.com/GadgetSteve/pyFileWhirlpool).

The portable python will let you run the python Whirlpool on any windows machine with an accessible USB port and the pure python should work on any machine that has Python 2 installed, (i.e. Some windows machines, (just about) all OS-X, most Linux installations, many mainframes/servers, clusters, etc., even RaspberryPi).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I expected to see something like a zip archive which you can extract and run the app immediately, but yes, I need full details of what you mean saying "you will need to extend the pure python implementation above"

Comment: Truly portable will be across OSes, (since you didn't specify one I assumed that you needed such).  I will post an extended version of the pure python to allow it to be used for files.

Comment: @lyricallywicked I have hacked the original code to allow it's use on files and uploaded to github - link is now in the modified answer.

Comment: I never used portable python and it seems like it will take some time for me to get into... But I wonder about the performance. Say, consider the PC from the year 2007-2008 with 1GB RAM and its user who wants to get a hash of a 1GB-sized file. What kind of experience will the user receive?

Comment: I haven't actually tried it on a pc with that little RAM but I have regularly run python on WinXP, the modified Whirlpool implementation I posted a link to above processes the file in 1MB chunks by default, it can be tweaked, so I would not expect the input file size to cause memory problems - it will just take a little time to process.  Note that the minimal install of portable python 2.7.6 which should be enough to run the linked script, is just 50-60 MB on the USB stick.